# QueryDSL and Enum inner fields persisting

Tags: java, enums, querydsl

I have enum with inner field:

```
public enum AccessMode {
    ALL(1),
    DEFAULT(2),
    //etc

    private int id;

    //constructor

    public int getId() {return id;}
}
```

What I want to do is read\save id value from\to DB, not string literal as default option.
Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990371/is-it-possible-to-use-a-enum-method-in-a-querydsl-query) asked 5 year ago, but maybe something have changed.

Comment: Which dialect are you using QueryDSL for? JPA? SQL? Mongo?

Comment: JPA. It seems that AttributeConvertor<EnumClass, PropertyClass can be used - I currently checking this.

Comment: In JPA an Enum field can only be mapped using its string value or its ordinal. It cant be done by a field. As JPA doesn't allow for it, QueryDSL can't write meaningful queries for it either. The answer to the question you linked is still correct.

USing an attribute converter you could make a mapping, but the mapping will have issues because you have to query with the field type (integer) but the metamodel will generate a field with the entity type (enum). So you're still going to run into trouble.

I either would convert the enum into an entity, or map the enum using the standard ordinal.